# How can I resolve this Dynamics AX 2009 Error?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

When doing a data dictionary synchronisation, I am getting the following error:

"There is already an object named 'I_1338SORTINGIDIDX' in the database."
"Synchronize failed on 1 tables"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall having the same situation. Normally the system will discover table indexes and recreate them if needed. It could be related to ID mismatch between your application and the database.

If you have a backup of the database in question, you could simply drop the index using the DROP INDEX I_1338SORTINGIDIDX
Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx

After dropping the index, synchronize again, so the index is recreated.

It appears to be a non-clustered index used for sorting, so it should be safe to remake it without much fuzz. If it was a clustered or primary index, it could prove to me more cumbersome.

Good luck!

Comment: We found a table called "dbo.dbo" containing the offending index. We dropped it, synchronised and the problem was gone. Much thanks for your input which put us on the right path. and saved us a lot of pain.